# Laravel login with more custom fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

I want a user to login using his/her id_number(school id number) only. Or if he forgets his id number, I want him to login using his Name, course and year graduated.

Is it possible to implement this using Laravel auth?
I am really new to laravel. I would appreciate if you could help me. 
Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

After you use `php artisan make:auth`

You can see in `LoginController`, there is a trait `AuthenticatesUsers`. The default auth is on `AuthenticatesUsers`. It can be modify by your own function by overriding `validateLogin`, `attemptLogin`, `credentials` , etc...

for example

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'ic_number' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('username', 'ic_number');
}
```